# How kafka decides the number of records to poll?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a kafka listener application which is basically consuming the message in list for example:-

```
public void consumeUniversalMetric(List<SomeClass> someClassList) {
//Do some processing
}
```

Lets say that the `spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=5`.

1. What happens if number of message is less than 5?
2. How much time does kafka waits before creating the batch of size 5?

Answer (score 2):

If Kafka receives less than 5 messages in `5000` milliseconds it will use the `pollTimeout` with `5000` ms by default.

> The timeout passed into Consumer.poll().

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/

If you want to configure it using Spring + Kafka use on your `application.yml` file

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        max.poll.interval.ms: 300000
```

Comment: Is it the `max.poll.interval.ms` or `fetch.max.wait` property which defines how long to wait before consuming the next batch of message?

Answer (score 0):

The two consumer properties that control this are `fetch.max.wait` and `fetch.min.bytes` - there is no `fetch.min.records` property so you have to estimate the minimum number of records (if you want to wait if there are less than 5).